# How should I parse large XML files in Perl?

Tags: xml, perl, sax

Does reading XML data like in the following code create the DOM tree in memory?

```
my $xml = new XML::Simple;

my $data = $xml->XMLin($blast_output,ForceArray => 1);
```

For large XML files should I use a [SAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_API_for_XML) parser, with handlers, etc.?

Comment: What do you want to do to the file? How much do you need to keep in memory for future operations? We can't tell you what to use without knowing what you specifically need to do.

Comment: By way of a data point, I have tried to use XML::Simple to parse the Wikimedia Commons XML dump, but that is to big (on an older desktop box running Ubuntu).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say yes to both.  The XML::Simple library will create the entire tree in memory and it's a large multiple on the size of the file.   For many applications if your XML is over 100MB or so, it'll be practical impossible to entirely load into memory in perl.  A SAX parser is a way of getting "events" or notifications as the file is read and tags are opened or closed.

Depending on your usage patterns, either a SAX or a DOM based parser could be faster: for example, if you are trying to handle just a few nodes, or every node, in a large file, the SAX mode is probably best.  For example, reading a large RSS feed and attempting to parse every item in it.

On the other hand, if you need to cross-reference one part of the file with another part, a DOM parser or accessing via XPath will make more sense - writing it in the "inside-out" manner that a SAX parser requires will be clumsy and tricky.

I recommend trying a SAX parser at least once, because the event-driven thinking required to do so is good exercise.

I've had good success with XML::SAX::Machines to set up SAX parsing in perl - if you want multiple filters and pipelines it's easy to set up.  For simpler setups (i.e 99% of the time) you just need a single sax filter (look at XML::Filter::Base) and tell XML::SAX::Machines to just parse the file (or read from filehandle) using your filter. [Here's a thorough article.](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2001/10/10/sax-filters.html)

Answer (score 15):

For large XML files, you can either use XML::LibXML, in DOM mode if the document fits in memory, or using the pull mode (see [XML::LibXML::Reader](http://search.cpan.org/~pajas/XML-LibXML-1.70/lib/XML/LibXML/Reader.pod)) or [XML::Twig](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Twig) (which I wrote, so I'm biased, but it works generally well for files that are too big to fit in memory).

I am not a fan of SAX, which is hard to use and in fact quite slow.

Comment: I'm using `XML::Twig` for large files

Comment: I like both `XML::Twig` and `XML::LibXML::Reader` but I tend to use the latter because it is much faster than Twig...

Answer (score 4):

I have not used the XML::Simple module before, but from the [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Simple/lib/XML/Simple.pm) it appears to create a simple hash in memory.  This is not a full DOM tree, but may well be enough for your requirements.

For large XML files, using a SAX parser would be faster and have a smaller memory footprint, but then it would again depend upon your needs.  If you just need to process the data in a serial fashion, then using [XML::SAX](http://search.cpan.org/~grantm/XML-SAX-0.96/SAX.pm) would probably suit your needs.  If you need to manipulate your whole tree, then maybe using something like [XML::LibXML](http://search.cpan.org/~pajas/XML-LibXML-1.70/LibXML.pod) would be better for you.

It is all horses for courses i'm afraid